# Remove class active on all data-filter on isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to completely hide 'all' button on my isotope portfolio and set active class to category 'book'. I cannot just delete line of code because I'm working on wordpress theme which have this feature build-in.

Im tryied this:

```
var $allFilter = $("li.filter:contains('all')")
$allFilter.removeClass("active");

var $Book = $("li.filter:contains('book')")
$Book.addClass("active")
```

And class 'active' is on 'book' and 'all' category but displays 'all' categoried items
Any ideas?

Comment: I would guess just changing the class will not trigger the filter to updated. But impossible to answer without more information

Comment: Dont know if this would trigger update because on document.load i got 2 categories with active classes.
If i could just remove active class on 'all' category...

Answer (score 0):

Try running that code in the console in chrome or firefox to see all the elements it matches. It might be that you need to run it after ajax has loaded content into the page.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/WeLqb
Look, cant trigger filter to update i got doubled active classes

Comment: This is at best a comment, not an answer. You have the rep to comment; please use it if you are asking the OP to "try something".

Comment: Try running that code in the console in chrome or firefox to see all the elements it matches. It might be that you need to run it after ajax has loaded content into the page.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. Everything what i needed to do was autoclick on button-category called "Book"

```
window.onload = function(){
var $Book = jQuery("li.filter:contains('book')")
$Book.find('span').trigger('click');
}
```